# MySQL skipping first row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have seen other people with that problem but the solutions I've seen aren't helping me, or I don't know how to use them :P

```
<?php
$ordre = "nom";
$croissance = "ASC";

if(isset($_GET["ordre"])){
    $ordre = $_GET["ordre"];
};  

if(isset($_GET["croissance"])){
    $croissance = $_GET["croissance"];
};

$con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('sdj_jeux', $con);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM jeux ORDER BY $ordre $croissance";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $con);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);  

$couleurcompteur = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $couleurcompteur += 1;
if($couleurcompteur % 2){
    $classe = "pale";   
} else {
    $classe = "fonce";  
    };
?>
```

My code is skipping the first row of my database and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Remove the line:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

The `while` loop will grab the first row on the first iteration.

Resulting code:

```
<?php
$ordre = "nom";
$croissance = "ASC";

if(isset($_GET["ordre"])){
    $ordre = $_GET["ordre"];
};  

if(isset($_GET["croissance"])){
    $croissance = $_GET["croissance"];
};

$con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('sdj_jeux', $con);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM jeux ORDER BY $ordre $croissance";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $con);

$couleurcompteur = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $couleurcompteur += 1;
if($couleurcompteur % 2){
    $classe = "pale";   
} else {
    $classe = "fonce";  
    };
?>
```

Comment: Great addendum above from @UnholyRanger. You should post this code to code review as well. Use PDO or `mysqli` instead of `mysql_*`.

Comment: I still do not understand why It was skipping the first row? @ConnorMcArthur

Answer (score 4):

Right here is your problem:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);  

$couleurcompteur = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
```

You call `mysql_fetch_array()` once before the `while`. This throws out the first row since you don't use it. Remove that un-needed call.

**NOTICE:** Do not use MySQL_* for it has been deprecated as of PHP 5.5. Use MySQLi_* or PDO instead